# Angular JS + Redirect not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ngroute

```
var weatherApp = angular.module('weatherApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngStorage']);

weatherApp.config(function ($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'html/views/search.html',
            controller: 'searchCtrl',
        })
        .when('/forecast',{
            templateUrl: 'html/views/forecast.html',
            controller: 'forecastCtrl',
        })
        .when('/login',{
            templateUrl: 'html/views/login.html',
            controller: 'loginCtrl',
        })
        .when('/logout', {
            controller: 'logoutCtrl',
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/',
        });
});
```

**logout controller**

```
weatherApp.controller('logoutCtrl', ["$scope", "$location", "$localStorage", function($scope, $location, $localStorage){
    $localStorage.removeItem("user_email");
    $localStorage.removeItem("user_password");
    console.log("coming in logout controller!!");
    $location.path("/login");
}]);
```

I have written above code to define routes for my site. For logout, I have defined controller as "logoutCtrl". But My code does not seem to work. When I hit SITE_URL/#/logout, it does not console log neither delete localStorage data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no template for state `logout`

> Angular uses an if (template) check before firing the controller

to fix that:

```
var weatherApp = angular.module('weatherApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngStorage']);

weatherApp.config(function ($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'html/views/search.html',
            controller: 'searchCtrl',
        })
        .when('/forecast',{
            templateUrl: 'html/views/forecast.html',
            controller: 'forecastCtrl',
        })
        .when('/login',{
            templateUrl: 'html/views/login.html',
            controller: 'loginCtrl',
        })
        .when('/logout', {
            template: " ", // <--- Notice, (" ") rather than ("")
            controller: 'logoutCtrl',
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/',
        });
});
```